# How does this sequential model work without a time distributed?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I followed a tutorial to make a Keras LSTM model that has 80 timesteps, looks at 80 words per timestep, and predicts 1 word at a time. Now that I'm making a different LSTM model with the functional API, I'm not sure how my other model works without a Time Distributed layer. I'm going to list the first LSTM model below. How is it that the following layer makes 80 separate predictions at different points in time in the same batch without a Time distributed layer?

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(15938, 150, input_length=80))
model.add(keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(1024))
model.add( keras.layers.Dense(15938, activation='softmax') ) 

arrayOfArraysToTrainOnInputF = np.empty( [80, 80], dtype=int )
arrayOfArraysToTrainOnTargetF = np.empty( [80, 15938], dtype=int )

model.train_on_batch( 
arrayOfArraysToTrainOnInputF,arrayOfArraysToTrainOnTargetF )
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer. The embedding operation causes the input to be of size (80,80,150), meaning 80 samples of 80 timesteps.